# Why is addition allowed in a constexpr function, but increment isn't?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer, constexpr

In the **[following example](http://ideone.com/ERZi8C)**:

```
//Case 1
constexpr int doSomethingMore(int x)
{
    return x + 1;
}

//Case 2
constexpr int doSomething(int x)
{
    return ++x;
}


int main()
{}
```

**Output:**

> prog.cpp: In function ‘constexpr int doSomething(int)’:
>   prog.cpp:12:1: error: expression ‘++ x’ is not a constant-expression

Why is Case 1 allowed but  Case 2 is not allowed?

Comment: Because "expression ‘++ x’ is not a constant-expression"? I'm not sure what else you want to hear.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Indeed, but why is it not a constant expression? Why does `x + 1` qualify's while `++x` doesn't? Seems to skip me at this moment for some reason.

Comment: Increment and decrement are explicitly forbidden in [expr.const]/2 to appear in constant expressions.

Comment: Erm. `{ auto a = x + 1; auto b = x + 1; assert(a == b); } { auto a = ++x; auto b = ++x; assert(a != b); }`.

Comment: Currently it is waaaay limited what you can do in constexpr. But wait just a little, in [C++14](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.htmlhttp://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3652.html) most limitations will be gone (and you might even get them sooner in Clang and gcc). ++x is no-go for C++11.

Comment: Because is `x+1` calculated and returned on the stack while `++x` increments x and then returns `x` on the stack - thus `x` is altered and is not a `constexpr`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes IIRC C++11 does not require `initializer_list`s to be able to appear in constant expressions (e.g. no constexpr ctor), though a proposal fixes that. But your example holds for any kind of list-initialization (not only for `initializer_list`s).

Comment: @IngeHenriksen: The question still has merit IMO: the *entire expression* is free of side effects and can be calculated at compile time - it is a `constexpr` in spirit.

Comment: @peterchen, yes, and that's why it's  allowed in C++14, but in C++11 `constexpr` functions must conform to a more functional programming style, i.e. avoiding state and mutable data, even local state.

Answer (score 8):

Case 1 doesn't modify anything, case 2 modifies a variable.  Seems pretty obvious to me!

Modifying a variable requires it to not be constant, you need to have mutable state and the expression `++x` modifies that state.  Since a `constexpr` function can be evaluated at compile-time there isn't really any "variable" there to modify, because no code is executing, because we're not at run-time yet.

As others have said, C++14 allows `constexpr` functions to modify their local variables, allowing more interesting things like `for` loops.  There still isn't really a "variable" there, so the compiler is required to act as a simplified interpreter at compile-time and allow limited forms of local state to be manipulated at compile-time.  That's quite a significant change from the far more limited C++11 rules.

Comment: and even more interesting things like compile-time infinite loops :)

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is indeed valid that by spirit/technicality of `constexpr` both `x+1` and `++x` are same. Where `x` is a local variable to the function. Hence there should be **no error** in any case.

This issue is now fixed with C++14. Here is the forked code and that [compiles fine with C++14](http://ideone.com/5Gj92Z).

Answer (score 1):

Constant expressions are defined in the last few pages of clause 5.

As a rough description, they are side-effect-free expressions that can be evaluated at compile-time (during translation).  The rules surrounding them are created with this principle in mind.